# Is this IC damaged or fake?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, log-amplifier

I am trying to test a [AD8307](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8307.pdf). Here are my connections:

[image: AD8307]

(pins not shown are left unconnected, and also pin 8).

I get a quiescent output voltage at pin 4 of about 850 mV with respect to ground, which, to my best understanding, means that the IC is fake.

What do you think?

**Note**: According to the datasheet, the input impedance of the IC is 1 kOhm. I am not working inside a microwave oven or near high voltage sparks, so, I can hardly imagine that the tiny pin 8 acts as an antenna or so to provide such a voltage discrepancy, but to make that sure, I tried to put it in a metal box and that made no difference.

Comment: Where did you get it from? Can you show us a photo of the IC?

Comment: Did you try grounding pin 8 through a ceramic capacitor?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany. Yes I did. But since the datasheet says 1 kOhm input impedance, I felt there is no need to add this here.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott. I'm not at my lab for now. But the IC looks exactly as it is shown in the datasheet.

Comment: Well, we don't know your power supply and other factors that could be contributing.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany. As indicated in the schematic 5V, with about 10 mv Ripple. The IC is not near anything radiating, since it is only being tested.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the 10mV of ripple, more about possible CM voltage wrt earth.

Comment: That's interesting (I don't really understand). Maybe could you explain that in an answer ?

Answer (score 4):

The inputs are clearly shown as AC coupled

[image]

I'd try this way before throwing that poor IC in the bin

BTW reading the datasheet before using a part is often a good idea.

Comment: "Is often a good idea": this year's diplomacy award goes to @carloc :D

Comment: @carloc. That's because I read the datasheet that I found that the input impedance of the IC is 1 kOhṁ. So, 1kOhm between pin 8 and ground. For me, that sounds like there is no need to couple with a small capacitor for a test. I tried with a capacitor between pin 8  and ground, though, giving no difference.

Comment: @MikeTex I hope you forgive me, didn't mean to be pedantic, everybody, even gurus, sometimes miss important points. In fact reading datasheets is sometimes tricky. In this case to an expert reader there are plenty of clues recalling attention on the topic beyond the DC in the title. For instance, single supply, common mode input voltage around 3V, the test scheme I posted and also various snippets of internal circuit with the input differential stage. My suggestion is to always read and understand the whole datasheet, especially contradictory points

Comment: BTw, I forgot to address your last doubt, 1kohm input impedance is small signal parameter to be used for small changes around bias point. Bias is about 3V in this case and shorting it to ground simplify switches off the input stage

Answer (score -1):

***Answer***

Your IC seems to be a RF signal amplifier, not power detector.  Perhaps you can try using a cheapy US$22 RF power detector AD8362, and detect RF transceiver signals.

***update 2021may03: or checking out microwave oven leakage***.

[image: ad8632]

---

***References***

(1) [How Can I read data from AD8361 RF Detector - RpiSE 2020mar1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109330/how-can-i-read-data-from-ad8361-rf-detector)5

(2) [Way to get signal strength from an RFID reader? - RpiSE 2020aug21](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116298/way-to-get-signal-strength-from-an-rfid-reader)

(3) [AD8361 RF Power Detector - Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8361.pdf)